# Analyzing dynamics of an object in a frictionless hemisphere

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Will a bead at the bottom of a frictionless hemisphere have a tendency to move up the if the hemisphere is rotating with an accelerated angular velocity[image: anglular velocity is not constant]

Comment: please supply a diagram.

Comment: What is up and down on this image?

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Please show some effort!

Comment: which way is gravity acting?

Comment: I think it is obvious that gravity is acting down to the left. *...bead at the bottom of a frictionless hemisphere.*

Comment: Same as having the mass on the end of a piece of string ie a simple pendulum.

Comment: @Farcher : Hmm, more like a *conical pendulum*, I think.

Comment: @sammygerbil I agree.

Answer (score 2):

#### My Assumptions:

1. Gravity is acting toward the left in your diagram.
2. The bead begins the experiment motionless at the lowest point in the hemisphere.

#### Question:

Will the bead climb up the **frictionless** hemisphere when the hemisphere is accelerated about its central axis (horizontal axis in diagram)?

#### Answer:

No, the bead will not move at all.

#### Reason:

The relative motion between the bead and the hemisphere is tangential to the surface of the bead.  Without friction, no force will be exchanged between the hemisphere and bead.  Without force, the bead will not be accelerated from its initial at-rest position.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the bead on a large flat rotating disk. It rolls outward, and continues rolling outward if there is nothing to stop it. Why? Because of inertia. Or, in the rotating frame of the disk, because of a 'fictitious' centrifugal force.

Now imagine that the disk gradually curves upwards towards the rim, so it looks more like the hemisphere. Does the bead keep moving upwards and outwards? No, it stops when the forces on it are balanced in the rotating frame - or the net force equals the centripetal force in the inertial frame of the stationary Earth.

Comment: James is correct : I overlooked your instruction that the situation is frictionless.